# How do I get the contents of the WSGI `environ` dictionary?

Tags: python, wsgi

I'm just expanding on the WSGI `def application...` example that you can find anywhere. So far, I haven't figured out how to return the contents of the `environ` dictionary.

```
#import json

def application(environ, start_response):
  status = '200 OK'

  # The output must be a "sequence of byte string values," not a
  # string. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/#a-note-on-string-types
  # and https://diveintopython3.net/strings.html#byte-arrays
  #output = b'Hello World!'          # Success!
  #output = str(environ)             # Nope
  #output = bytes(environ)           # Nope
  #output = bytes(str(environ))      # Nope
  #output = b'str(environ)'          # Nope, but eye-rollingly funny
  #
  #jsonEnviron = json.dumps(environ) # Nope - error says environ is of
  #output = bytes(jsonEnviron)       # Nope - type 'TextIOWrapper'

  response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                      ('Content-Length', str(len(output))),
                      ('X-Clacks-Overhead', 'GNU Terry Pratchett')]

  start_response(status, response_headers)

  return [output]
```

If the solution is out there, my Duck Duck Go searches aren't finding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with [@AKX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/51685/akx)'s answer for a while, I went to look for a way to get debug output of POST data and came across [this page](https://code-examples.net/en/q/604e1). That pretty much handled everything, with pretty printing thrown in for free! So, here's my final server test/debug script:

```
from json import dumps
from os import path
from pprint import pformat
from urllib import parse

def application(environ, start_response):
  status = '200 OK'

  # show the environment:
  output = [b'<pre>']
  output.append(pformat(environ).encode('utf-8'))

  output.append(b'\n\nPATH_INFO: ' + environ['PATH_INFO'].encode('utf-8'))
  filepath, filename = path.split(environ['PATH_INFO'])
  filebase, fileext = path.splitext(filename)
  output.append(b'\nPath = ' + filepath.encode('utf-8'))
  output.append(b'\nFile = ' + filename.encode('utf-8'))
  output.append(b'\nFile Base = ' + filebase.encode('utf-8'))
  output.append(b'\nFile Ext = ' + fileext.encode('utf-8'))

  output.append(b'\n\nQUERY_STRING is\n' + environ['QUERY_STRING'].encode('utf-8'))
  queryDict = parse.parse_qs(environ['QUERY_STRING'])
  output.append(b'\n\nQUERY_STRING as a dict:\n')
  output.append(dumps(queryDict, sort_keys=True, indent=2).encode('utf-8'))

  output.append(b'</pre>')

  #create a simple form:
  output.append(b'\n\n<form method="post">')
  output.append(b'<input type="text" name="test">')
  output.append(b'<input type="submit">')
  output.append(b'</form>')

  if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST':
    # show form data as received by POST:
    output.append(b'\n\n<h1>FORM DATA</h1>')
    output.append(b'\n<pre>')
    output.append(pformat(environ['wsgi.input'].read()).encode('utf-8'))
    output.append(b'</pre>')

  # send results
  output_len = sum(len(line) for line in output)

  response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html'),
                      ('Content-Length', str(output_len)),
                      ('X-Clacks-Overhead', 'GNU Terry Pratchett')]

  start_response(status, response_headers)

  return output
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply `bytes()` a dictionary, because there is no canonical binary representation of one without defining the format in one way or another.

```
return [repr(environ).encode('utf-8')]
```

should be a good start.

As you said, the return value of a WSGI application must be an iterable of `bytes`es, and if you just want the output for reading, repr is as good a representation as any. For machine use, you might want `json.dumps().encode()`, etc.